# Pine Script How to remove whole number from decimal

Tags: pine-script

```
decimal = 69.143
```

I only want to keep 0.143, how do I remove the whole number 69?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it.

```
decimal = 69.143

newValue = decimal - int(decimal)
```